# YUI JSON Datatable: how to dynamically change the request without POST

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I have been playing with server side sorting/paging using YUI DataTable, and everything is working as expected.

I want to be able to have something like a form input element to restrict the rows in the table, and my json proxy can handle it, for example:

```
new YAHOO.util.DataSource("/php/json_proxy.php?")
```

will return everything, whereas

```
new YAHOO.util.DataSource("/php/json_proxy.php?var=blah")
```

will restrict it to only rows with the column var equalling 'blah' show up.

How can I do this without a HTML POST (refresh of the page), i.e. make changes to the datasource's request string via things like a select box, checkbox etc.

Sorry if you can't follow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with the following (assuming `myDataTable` references your datatable.

```
// Sends a request to the DataSource for more data
var oCallback = {
    success : myDataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable,
    failure : myDataTable.onDataReturnAppendRows,
    scope : myDataTable
};
this.myDataSource.sendRequest("var=blah", oCallback);
```

The section about [data retrieval](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/#data) on YUI has a lot of information about this.  There's a whole section about retrieving data at runtime.